# How to create a tree from flat array?

Tags: javascript, typescript

There is a flat array with id, parentid links. The array example is:

```
   let e = [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "descr": "Те",
        "moddate": "2023-02-09T13:37:46.366961",
        "isgroup": true
      },  {
        "id": 2,
        "descr": "Те",
        "moddate": "2023-02-09T13:37:46.366961",
        "parentid": 1
      }];
```

I have tried to create a tree:

```
let roots = e.filter((item) => !item?.parentid).map((e) => {e.children = [];return e;});
```

```
  const children = e.filter((item) => item?.parentid);

  function setChild(children) {
    children.forEach((element) => {
      const { parentid } = element;
      const root = roots.find((e) => e.id === parentid);
      if (root) root.children.push(element);
    });
  }

  setChild(children);
```

I expect result when node has children elements:

```
 let res = [
      {
            "id": 1,
            "descr": "Те",
            "moddate": "2023-02-09T13:37:46.366961",
            "isgroup": true,
            "children": [{
            "id": 2,
            "descr": "Те",
            "moddate": "2023-02-09T13:37:46.366961",
            "parentid": 1
          }]
     }];
```

So, my problem is that I dont make recursion, probably

Comment: Provide your input and the expected output.

Comment: I have updated a question

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems to work for the provided data. I think it does not work for a tree with height larger than 2, because you add a `children` array only to root nodes, but children can have children themselves. Similarly, you have to search for the parent in all nodes, not just roots. Otherwise, I think it works.

For fun, a one-liner as example:

```js
let e = [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "descr": "Те",
        "moddate": "2023-02-09T13:37:46.366961",
        "isgroup": true
      },  {
        "id": 2,
        "descr": "Те",
        "moddate": "2023-02-09T13:37:46.366961",
        "parentid": 1
      },  {
        "id": 3,
        "descr": "Те",
        "moddate": "2023-02-09T13:37:46.366961",
        "parentid": 1
      },  {
        "id": 4,
        "descr": "Те",
        "moddate": "2023-02-09T13:37:46.366961",
        "parentid": 2
      }];

const tree = e.map(n => ({...n, children: []})).reduce( (t,n, _, e) => 'parentid' in n ? (( n.parent = e.find(en => en.id === n.parentid)).children.push(n), t) : [...t, n], [])

console.log(tree)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: how to add a link to parent element instead parentid?

Comment: @user13314476 At the step when you push the child into its parent's `children` array, you have both parent and child and you can do `child.parent = parent`. I have updated the one-liner so that it also sets the parent property.

Answer (score 2):

Sample implementation

**Logic**

- Separate nodes with `parentid` and without `parentid`
- Loop through `nodesWithParent` and find the matching parent from `nodesWithOutParent`.
- If match found, push the march to the `children` node of the match.
- If match not found, push the node to the list without parent id.
- Retun the list

**Code**

```js
let e = [
  {
    id: 1,
    descr: "Те",
    moddate: "2023-02-09T13:37:46.366961",
    isgroup: true,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    descr: "Те",
    moddate: "2023-02-09T13:37:46.366961",
    parentid: 1,
  },
];

function setChild(list) {
  const result = [];
  const nodesWithParent = list.filter((item) => item?.parentid !== undefined);
  const nodesWithOutParent = list.filter((item) => item?.parentid === undefined);
  nodesWithParent.forEach(node => {
    const match = nodesWithOutParent.find(item => item.id === node.parentid)
    if (match) {
      if (match.children) {
        match.children.push(node)
      } else {
        match.children = [node];
      }
    } else {
      nodesWithOutParent.push(match)
    }
  })
  return nodesWithOutParent
}

console.log(setChild(e));
```